# UDP server. Capable of sending or just receiving

Tags: node.js, sockets, udp

I was working in node.js TCP server environment for a long time, and I got used to TCP socket architecture.
Right now I want to make an UDP server with 'dgram' native module. I've successfully received a packet, but how can I send something back to the client.
Does UDP server support both sending and receiving or just receiving? I can't find anything about sending in node's docs.
I've found UdpClient class in C# has a method .Send() so there has to be some way.

Comment: Did you find a way to block `UDP` at all? That would make a great barrier for [DNS Reflection Defense](https://blogs.akamai.com/2013/06/dns-reflection-defense.html)?

Comment: What do You sir mean by _block_?
Isn't unopened port enough to block a incoming packets?

Comment: Ehmm, could you post some code? To your question, does that not work http://nodejs.org/api/dgram.html#dgram_socket_send_buf_offset_length_port_address_callback ? Also I do not think, you can...well there must be a way to make `VoIP` work, but I do not know how to communicate with the client over `UDP`...

Comment: It does work. But isn't that a method for a client? I'm asking about the server sending the packet **to** the client

Comment: Ehmm, this is definitely a method to send from the node.js server. But do not ask me how to receive an `UDP` datagram on the client side.

Comment: This sounds legit https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nodejs/Tnl57UySliE (node.js and socket.io) and this https://journal.paul.querna.org/articles/2010/12/15/udp-in-node-js/ :D